# Using Numeric Keys with CakePhp FormHelper Select

Tags: php, cakephp, select, cakephp-1.3, formhelper

I'm using the FormHelper (cake 1.3) to create a select box from an array. The array uses numbers as keys but the select box ignores those numbers and uses a zero-based index for the select box option values. I've tried typing the array key to a string using both (string)$key and strval($key) with no luck. The select options work when I prepend a letter before the numeric key (i.e. 'c'.$key ) but I'd like to avoid this hack.

Is there a way to force FormHelper to use the actual numeric keys without prepending a letter? Any help would be appreciated.

See the following code for illustration:

```
// $category_list looks like this
Array
(
    [164] => Antiques & Art
    [83] => Baby/Children Needs
    [176] => Boats/Marine/Fishing
    [222] => Books & Magazines
    [287] => Building Materials
    [215] => Business
    [175] => Caravans & Motor Homes
    [169] => Cars & Other Vehicles
    [127] => Clothing & Accessories
    [92] => Computers & Electronics
    [358] => Farm & Agriculture
    [235] => Garage Sales/Yard Sales
    [309] => Garden & Yard
    [178] => General Merchandise
    [138] => Health & Beauty
    [186] => Hobbies & Collectables
    [63] => Household
    [234] => Information
    [388] => Motorbikes & Scooters
    [206] => Musical Instruments
    [449] => Notices
    [305] => Pets and Accessories
    [242] => Positions Vacant
    [236] => Real Estate & Rentals
    [243] => Services
    [143] => Sports Equipment
    [308] => Tools & Equipment
    [300] => Travel & Holiday
)

// Output category select box
echo $form->select(
 'category',
 $category_list,
 $category,
 array('id'=>'SearchCategories')
);

// Outputs like this
<option value="1">Antiques &amp; Art</option>
<option value="2">Baby/Children Needs</option>
<option value="3">Boats/Marine/Fishing</option>
<option value="4">Books &amp; Magazines</option> 
...

// I'd like it to output like this
<option value="164">Antiques &amp; Art</option>
<option value="83">Baby/Children Needs</option>
<option value="176">Boats/Marine/Fishing</option> 
<option value="222">Books &amp; Magazines</option> 
...
```

Comment: Are you using `debug($this->find('all'))` or `debug($this->find('list'))` to display `$category_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you stuck to conventions you should be able to do $this->Form->input('category_id') and it will just work (with passing $categories to the view). Cake does use the key of the array for the value in the select so you must be passing the wrong data.

I am guessing you have done sort() on the array which will reset all the keys. Look at the php manual for the method that sorts by value keeping keys intact, asort() iirc

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me realize that the array_unshift function that I was using on the array was reindexing the array. I guess sometimes you're too close to the code to see the obvious. Thanks.